# How do I resolve modules that get processed by exports-loader in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using webpack 2.1.0-beta.20 and am getting a `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve` error when trying to build.

I have a file `EmsWorkerProxy.js` that does not export a module, so I'm using [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader) so that I can `require()` it in my script.

On top of that, I also want to turn that into a web worker, so I'm chaining [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack/worker-loader) to that.

I'd love to not use relative or absolute paths. The scripts are in a vendor directory, so I'm trying to add this to my webpack.conf.js:

`resolve: {
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      'src',
      'vendor'
    ]
  },`

Unfortunately, it seems like webpack still can't resolve anything.

The line in my app that does
`const EmsWorkerProxy = require('worker!exports?EmsWorkerProxy!EmsWorkerProxy');` causes:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'EmsWorkerProxy'`

Am I not using webpack correctly?

Comment: webpack config files, are just like any other javascript file.  So you could do things like   `path.join(__dirname, 'vendor')`  etc.

Comment: Using a path doesn't seem to work either.  Here's an example that works:

`const EmsWorkerProxy = require('exports?EmsWorkerProxy!../vendor/flac/EmsWorkerProxy');`

But I'd like to avoid having to write the relative path in there. Instead, I just want to do this:

`const EmsWorkerProxy = require('exports?EmsWorkerProxy!EmsWorkerProxy');`

I added `path.join(__dirname, 'vendor/flac')` to my resolve.modules array but that also didn't work.